# YouTube DatavAPI v3を使って動画をアップロードできない

Tags: youtube-data-api

YouTube DatavAPI v3を使って動画を public でアップロードしたところ、「利用規約とポリシー：YouTube によってこの動画は非公開になりました 」というメッセージが表示され、privte表示となり、意図したpublicにはなりません。

もしかしたら、OAuth同意画面におけるスコープの指定をしていないのが原因かもしれません。
OAuth認証の申請は必要でしょうか？
またその時に必要なスコープとしては、以下がそれらしく見えるのですが、
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload
これだけでよろしいでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

●追加分
該当のコードを記します。

var video = new Video();
video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
video.Snippet.Title = title;
video.Snippet.Description = description;
video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22";
video.Status = new VideoStatus();
video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";
var filePath = moviePath;

PrivacyStatusを、publicではなく、private、unlistedにすればアップロードができ、異常なメッセージも出ません。

Comment: 動画の内容に問題があり (著作権侵害等)、審査によって非公開になっている可能性があります。

Comment: 動画の内容には問題がないと考えられます。手動でアップロードするとできますので。

Comment: どなたか、OAuth認証のスコープの設定をこうしたらAP
Iでアップロードできた、という情報を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 少なくとも OAuth の関係は薄いはずです。認証認可は API でリクエストを送って動画をアップロードし終わることができたのであれば既にクリアしている部分である一方で、お困りの事象は API リクエストが終わった後に起こっていることに見えました。　／　具体的にどういうコードでどのようにアップロードしているのかの情報があると、もう少し何か考えられるかもしれません。[問題を再現できるような短いサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)があるとベストです。質問を [edit] してみてください。

Comment: nekketsuuu様
コメントありがとうございます。
問題の現象は、APIでアップロードしたとほぼ同時に起こります。人手によるペナルティではなく、YouTube側の自動判断のように感じます。
該当コードを付記しましたので、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こちらに、OAuthに因るような記述がありました。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63937000/cant-upload-video-on-youtube-with-apis-v3
ただ、具体的に、OAuthのスコープの設定をどうしたらよいかの記述はありませんでした。